# Problema con select sin where a una base de datos desde php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```html
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','alumno','radius');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL:";
exit();
}

$query="SELECT id,nombre,autor FROM canciones";
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("iss",$id,$nombre,$autor);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
if ($stmt->num_rows>0)
{
 $stmt->bind_result($id,$nombre,$autor);
?>

<html>
<body>
 <h1>LISTADO DE CANCIONES DISPONIBLE</h1><br />
  <table>  
  <tr> <th><b>Canciones Disponibles</th><th><b>ID</th><th><b>NOMBRE</th><th><b>AUTOR</th>
</tr>
<?php

while ($stmt->fetch()){
?> 

<tr> 
 <td> <?php echo strtoupper($id);?></td>
 <td> <?php echo strtoupper($nombre);?></td>
 <td> <?php echo strtoupper($autor);?></td>
</tr> 
 
<?php
}
?>
</table>
 <br>
<table>
 <tr><td><a href="peticiones.php"><button  btn" >Pedir una cancion...</button></a></td></tr>
 </table><br>
  </body>
 </html>   
<?php
}
else
{
?>

<?php
$mysqli->close();
?> </body>
</html>
```

Estoy intentando hacer un select a una base de datos pero la pagina se me queda en blanco. No se si esta haciendo algo

Adjunto el codigo.

Comment: Vamos a empezar por lo basico. Se conecta a la base de datos? ese query cuantos registros trae? termina?

Comment: Si ya lo solucionaste, acepta la respuesta que lo solucionó (o la que te dió la base para solucionarlo), o agrega una con la solución, en caso que no haya sido propuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varios problemas en el código de arriba. El que crea el problema que ves (con la página en blanco) es que hay un `else {` que no se cierra y por ello obtienes un error de "Final inesperado del documento" y no se procesa el código.

La solución es simple: cierra la llave del `else` y ya se ejecutará todo.

```
<?php
}
else
{
?>

<?php
}
$mysqli->close();
?>  </body>
</html>
```

---

Ahora ya verás contenido en la página, pero seguirá habiendo otros errores que no sé si ocurren porque has reducido el código que compartes en la pregunta: se usan variables que no están definidas (`$id`, `$nombre` y `$autor`); y se hace un `bind_param` pero en la sentencia SQL no hay parámetros a los que hacer un bind.

Comment: Gracias ye me funciona

Comment: Genial, ¿cuál era el problema al final?

Comment: La llave sin cerrar

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que de error esté en este bloque.

```
  $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','alumno','radius');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL:";
exit();
}
```

Al darte error en la conexión el exit(), impediría la ejecución del programa de ahí que la página se te quede en blanco. Comprueba los datos de la BBDD. También puedes meterle un string al exit() para ver si está dando el error ahí, de la siguiente manera:

```
exit("Error en la conexión");
```